# three.js export using blender version 2.65 does not works

Tags: javascript, svg, 3d, three.js, blender

I created an SVG object using Inkscape, imported it to blender version 2.65, converted it into 3d by the options provided in blender, and tried to export it to three.js .

When it is exported to other formats (eg : obj , X3D) it works fine and the exported js contains values.

However, when it is exported to three.js, the verticies / co-ordinates are empty. I used the latest version(2.65) add on. Below is the three.js file I exported (it contains no vertices)

How do I resolve this ?

```
 {

    "metadata" : {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 0,
        "faces"         : 0,
        "normals"       : 0,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [],
        "materials"     : 0,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 0
        },

    "scale" : 1.000000,
    "materials" : [],
    "vertices" : [],
    "morphTargets" : [],
    "normals" : [],
    "colors" : [],
    "uvs" : [],
    "faces" : [],
    "bones" : [],
    "skinIndices" : [],
    "skinWeights" : [],
    "animations" : []
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I am having the exact same problem, tried selecting the object(s) with no luck exporting. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @nickspiel kindly refer this [link](http://myfablab.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/making-a-mesh-object-in-blender-from-a-svg-file/) , here i followed the steps and got solution

Comment: +1 I was missing the vital 'convert to mesh' step. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I had simular problem. I have tried several Blender to THREE.js exporters. One of them gave me good result.

But it didn't work if I didn't selected the exporting object .

Try to *select* exported object and then run export procedure again.

Comment: Thanks for replying , i had followed the [link](http://myfablab.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/making-a-mesh-object-in-blender-from-a-svg-file/) it works only for some times. I had tried it many,but can't get the correct at sequence, don't know what went wrong